# Ubuntu 18.04: Error during compilation using Truffle: How to install the updated version

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.  I have installed Truffle from the following site:

[Truffle for Linux](https://www.codeooze.com/blockchain/ethereum-dev-environment-2019/)

I am trying to execute an application from the following site:

[Petshop Tutorial](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop)

I am able to create the temporary file:

```
    @lc2530hz:~/pet-shop-tutorial$ truffle unbox pet-shop You can improve web3's peformance when     running Node.js versions older than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt package in your project

    Starting unbox...
    =================

    ✔ Preparing to download box ✔ 
      Downloading 
      npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to     chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies. 
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated 
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents: 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.13 
npm WARN pet-shop@1.0.0 No description 
npm WARN pet-shop@1.0.0 No repository field. 
✔ cleaning up temporary files 
✔ Setting up box

    Unbox successful, sweet!

    Commands:

      Compile:        truffle compile   
      Migrate:        truffle migrate   
      Test contracts:   truffle test   
      Run dev server: npm run dev

    @lc2530hz:~/pet-shop-tutorial$
```

However I am getting error in compilation

```
$ truffle compile
You can improve web3's peformance when running Node.js versions older than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt package in your project

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✔ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
✔ Downloading compiler. Attempt #1.
Error: Could not find __Truffle__NotFound.sol from any sources; imported from /home/zulfi/pet-shop-tutorial/contracts/adoption.sol
    at Resolver.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:53:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:5:42)
    at <anonymous>
Truffle v5.1.27 (core: 5.1.27)
Node v8.10.0
```

@lc2530hz:~/pet-shop-tutorial$

Somebody please guide me.

Have I installed an older version? Please tell me how to install the updated version for Ubuntu 18.04?

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

I got the clue from the following link:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/trufflesuite.com/issues/102

which says that the problem hasbeen solved at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090043/truffle-compile-failing-parsererror-expected-token-lparen-got-identifier-funct

which says that I was missing a bracket.

After that I was also making mistakes like:

1) wrong spelling for memory data type
2) wrong spelling for require

Zulfi.